# Fileserver with dynamic files

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, file-server

This may sound a bit odd, but I am trying to make it so that the files that get served can be chosen dynamically. In details, I want to perform 2 operations.

1. For all .txt files, replace `{USER}` with the current username.
2. Some files will appear in multiple directories, but I don't want them to take up additional storage. So if any of those files is requested, I want to server the one real file that I have.

Now, I could just implement the SFTP protocol in some language like java, and do this myself. However, I don't really feel like re-implementing the SFTP protocol. After all, I need is the normal protocol, but I change the serve function a bit. Is there an easy way to deal with this?

Note that it doesn't need to be SFTP, as long as it's safe and it supports authentication, I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do with the first operation, but I think the second one can be solved with a symbolic link.

Let's say you want to have a file called filename.txt appear in both /path1/ and /path2/

You can place filename.txt in /path1/, then you can do:

```
ln -s /path1/filename.txt /path2/filename.txt
```

The real file is still inside path1, but will appear as if it was also in path2